# Can we get user details before the app is opened for the first time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an Android App. It is hosted on Play Store. Have integrated Firebase Analytics in it. The analytics works when the app is opened and some interaction is done on the app.

While the app is installed for the first time and not opened yet, is there a way I can get the google play store account user name of the person who downloaded the app?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.  Firebase Analytics doesn't know anything about the Google user account that downloaded the app.  The data has been fully anonymized.  Even if you sign in the user with Firebase Authentication with Google sign-in, the user could choose an account on the device that's different than the one that downloaded the app.